# How to pipe specific cmd output line to another batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, active-directory, dsquery

How to pipe specific cmd output line to another batch?

For example:

```
command DSQUERY USER -samid *loginname* | DSGET USER -loscr
```

It finds what user in AD has in his Logon script field, what is actual login script name. I want to pipe this output to another batch file which opens login script file for this specific user.

BUT output of the above command outputs three lines:

```
loscr
"script name"
dsget succeeded
```

How to suppress first and third lines and to pipe only output from second line?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('command DSQUERY USER -samid *loginname*') do (
   if not defined second_line set "second_line=%%a"
)

DSGET USER -loscr %second_line%
```

?

Comment: npocmaka: Thanks. After I run batch with script you advised, cmd stops responding and doesn't provide any output. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: remove `@echo off` to see what happens...As I have no DS on my machine I cant test the script...

Comment: npocmaka: without @echo it shows that it stuck/stops responding after last bracket (or before command DSGET USER -loscr %second_line% ). Thanks

Comment: @alex change `if not defined second_line set "second_line=%%a"` with `echo %%a` to see the output of for loop.Ensure that the `command DSQUERY USER -samid *loginname*` is the thing you want to execute....